# execute function from package oracle in Explain plan window

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to obtain the results of the execute explain plan in ORACLE for a procedure in a package.

I use this sentence but I have the error ORA-00905: missing keyword

`call PK_MTMPLBO_TC_V01.FILL('MENSUAL', 'CARBON');`

How can I execute the sentence?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is the return type of the function ???

Comment: where are you running this from?

Comment: It's a procedure, not a function. I've editted the post. PL/SQL Developer

Answer (score 1):

To execute a procedure syntax is as below :

Declare
....

begin
PK_MTMPLBO_TC_V01.FILL('MENSUAL', 'CARBON');
end;